# Copy and Paste Header record into detail

Tags: text-processing, awk

Observed there is a position changed for string datatype after count was appended at the end.

```
       awk '$2=="H" {x = substr($3,1,4); next} {$(NF+1) = x} 1'
```

Input:

```
12      H   0003A 
12305245D   2500 AB   5454 87870001A 
12305245D   2500 ABC  5454 87870002A 
12305245D   2500 ABCD 5454 87870003A
```

Expected Output :

```
12      H   0003A 
12305245D   2500 AB   5454 87870001A 0003 
12305245D   2500 ABC  5454 87870002A 0003
12305245D   2500 ABCD 5454 87870003A 0003
```

Actual Output:

```
12      H   0003A 
12305245D   2500 AB 5454 87870001A 0003
12305245D   2500 ABC 5454 87870002A 0003
12305245D   2500 ABCD 5454 87870003A 0003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the field separator to an empty string with `-F ''`, you are telling awk to treat each character as a separate field. So `$` is *never* equal to `H` (and `$3` can never have the indicated substring). Instead, use the default (whitespace) separator.

Also you seem to want to add the substring as a separate delimited field `print $0, x` rather than appending it as a string (`$0 = $0 x`)

```
$ awk '$2=="H" {x = substr($3,1,4)} $2!="H" {print $0, x}' input
12305245D   2500 AB   5454 87870001A  0003
12305245D   2500 ABC  5454 87870002A  0003
12305245D   2500 ABCD 5454 87870003A 0003
```

A simplified version:

```
$ awk '$2=="H" {x = substr($3,1,4); next} {print $0, x}' input
12305245D   2500 AB   5454 87870001A  0003
12305245D   2500 ABC  5454 87870002A  0003
12305245D   2500 ABCD 5454 87870003A 0003
```

**NOTE** these answers **strictly retain** the position of the input fields: the variable spacing of the final column is a result of the variable amount of trailing whitespace **in your posted input**.

Comment: Thanks for the command. I have faced another issue whenever string datatype present and UNIX command changed the position of fixed width file. Any way to retain the position of string types?

Comment: @Chakkara please see updated answer